# Accessing members like array?

Tags: c++, c++11, strict-aliasing, type-punning

Due to reading a lot of warnings not to use unions like this:

```
union rgba
{
    struct
    {
        uint8_t r, g, b, a;
    } components;
    uint8_t index[4];
    uint32_t value;
};
```

because this is undefined behavior, I decided to keep things simple like so:

```
struct rgba
{
    uint8_t r, g, b, a;
};
```

but it so happened that sometimes I indeed do need to access `r`, `g`, `b` and `a` in a loop using indexes, otherwise I have to duplicate pretty long code for each component separately.

So I came up with this:

```
struct rgba
{
    u8 r, g, b, a;

    constexpr u8& operator[](size_t x)
    {
        return const_cast<u8*>(&r)[x];
    }
};
```

This relies on the assumption that `r`, `g`, `b` and `a` are placed in linear fashion in the memory, with no hidden boilerplate in between, and the compiler retains the variable order.

With this, I can access the components just like I wanted:

```
rgba c;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    c[i] = i ^ (i + 7);
c.a = 0xFF;
```

1. Since I made pretty big assumptions, I'm pretty sure that this is even more undefined behavior than using unions for type punning. Am I correct?
2. How else can I achieve similar design?

   1. I'd like to avoid writing `c.r() = 5` if possible since it looks funny.
   2. Having accessors such as `c.components[RED]` uses macros, and I like to avoid macros.
   3. Replacing macros from point 2. with enums will look ugly when one takes into account namespaces needed to access such enum. Imagine `c.components[Image::Channels::Red]`.

Comment: Why don't you use then `std::array<uint8_t,4>`, should be safe and fast enough

Comment: Because to access its components, unless everyone in the project knows that the color model is BGRA, I need to introduce `enum` ← see point 2.3.

Comment: It is usually easier to do this in reverse: keep a `uint32_t` which contains all rgba combined, and provide accessors like `uint8_t r()` etc. In the case of `uint8_t == unsigned char`, you can even alias the `uint32_t` with `uint8_t`, à la `uint8_t& r()`.

Comment: @dyp Yep, I thought about this (point 2.1.) but I wonder if there's anything I missed.

Comment: Using free functions, you'd get `r(c)`, which might look less funny? Or `red(color)`, or `red_component(color)`.

Comment: I wonder what of the original union approach is UB. GLM seems to use exactly that ( https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/master/glm/detail/type_vec4.hpp )....

Comment: @Marco13 Type punning through unions is UB in C++, but allowed in C, so gcc and clang support it as an extension in C++, too.

Comment: The `const_cast` looks really suspicious. I understand it's there because `constexpr` implies `const` for member functions in C++11 (but not any more in C++14), but IMHO you should use a `constexpr u8 const& operator[](size_t) const;` plus a `u8& operator[](size_t);` overload instead (the latter also being `constexpr` in C++14).

Comment: `const_cast<u8*>(&r)[x]` uses pointer arithmetic on a non-array, which is problematic (UB). But if `u8` is a typedef for `unsigned char`, you could get away with `reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(this)[x]`, with an additional `static_assert(sizeof(*this) == 4, "!");` and `static_assert(std::is_pod<rgba>::value, "!");`

Comment: Yes, `u8` is indeed `uint8_t` - sorry, I pasted the class from project and forgot to change that.

Comment: (Also @dyp ) I think I misread this. GLM does not create a union of the contents, but only uses them to "alias" the 4 components as (r,g,b,a) or (x,y,z,w). The actual access with the `[]` operator is then roughly as described in the question (as far as I can tell from [the code](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/master/glm/detail/type_vec4.inl#L215) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard gives you the answer about the question 1:

> **9.2/15:**  Nonstatic data members of a class with the same access control are allocated so that later members have higher addresses
>   within a class object. The order of allocation of non-static data
>   members with diﬀerent access control is unspeciﬁed. **Implementation
>   alignment requirements might cause two adjacent members not to be
>   allocated immediately after each other;** so might requirements for
>   space for managing virtual functions and virtual base classes.

There is a broad range of options for answer to the question 2. If you like the array notation:

- why not use a `switch()` to safely return the reference to the correct element.
- or better, why not replace your members by a real array ?

The first one would look like:

```
struct rgba2
{
    uint8_t r, g, b, a;
    constexpr uint8_t& operator[](size_t x)
    {
        assert(x>=0 && x<4);
        switch (x){
            case 0: return r; 
            case 1: return g;  
            case 2: return b;  
            case 3: return a; 
            //default: throw(1);  // not possible with constexpr
        }
    }
};
```

And the second:

```
struct rgba3
{
    enum ergb { red, green, blue, alpha};
    uint8_t c[alpha+1];
    constexpr uint8_t& operator[](ergb x)
    {
        assert(x>=0 && x<4);
        return c[x];
    }
};
```

[live demo](https://ideone.com/u8lvtx)

Comment: `static_assert(sizeof(rgba) == 4, "!");` can be used to work around this particular issue. Though that does not ensure the program will compile everywhere of course, it ensures that this issue won't occur on C++ implementations where it does compile.

Comment: *"not possible with constexpr"* It is in fact possible, and the preferred way to report errors in constant expressions: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Uedhwayol6ZrykD6 Actually, the `assert` has the same effect here on constant expressions, though I'm not sure if that's portable.

Comment: Though I should probably add that the `switch` is not allowed in C++11 constexpr functions. It is allowed since C++14. And the `assert` isn't allowed either in C++11, probably (the implementation of `assert` is not specified AFAIK, but C++11 constexpr functions are very restrictive).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this efficiently in a standards compliant way, by using a static array of pointers to members.

The memory overhead is one array per class. The code generated is identical to a direct member access when the index is known at compile time, in optimized builds.

Here's some example code ([Source](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=230443)):

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class Vector3
{
public:
   Vector3(const T &xx, const T &yy, const T &zz) :
      x(xx), y(yy), z(zz)
   {
   };

   T& operator[](size_t idx)
   {
      return this->*offsets_[idx];
   };

   const T& operator[](size_t idx) const
   {
      return this->*offsets_[idx];
   };

public:
   T x,y,z;
private:
   static T Vector3::* const offsets_[3];
};

template<class T>
T Vector3<T>::* const Vector3<T>::offsets_[3] =
{
   &Vector3<T>::x,
   &Vector3<T>::y,
   &Vector3<T>::z
};

int main()
{
   Vector3<float> vec(1,2,3);
   vec[0] = 5;
   std::cout << vec.x << std::endl;
}
```